# CMake sub-folder structure?

Tags: c++, cmake

My folder structure is like so...

```
Project2

CMakeLists.txt
lib
--include
--src
proj
--include
--src
test
--include
--src
```

I have the below CMakeLists.txt. As you can see the cmake commands for all 3 sub folders are included in this one. I dont think that is the best way. I think it is best to have a CMakeLists.txt focus on one folder only.

I would like to break this up so that lib, proj and test folders each to have a CMakeLists.txt but to still be part of the whole project. Is this possible?

When i generate my project using visual studio (cmake "Visual Studio 2017") i would like to see lib, proj and test have their own projects and be part of the solution.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)
project (Project2)

include (CTest)

# The version number.
set (Project2_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (Project2_VERSION_MINOR 0)

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
# so that we will find Project1Config.h
include_directories ("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

set (LIB_SRCS lib/include/example_lib.h lib/src/example_lib.cpp)
set (PROJECT_SRCS proj/include/example.h proj/src/example.cpp)
set (TEST_SRCS test/src/example_add.cpp test/src/example_subtract.cpp)

# add library
add_library (lib ${LIB_SRCS})

# add the executable
add_executable (Project2 proj/src/main.cpp ${PROJECT_SRCS})
target_link_libraries (Project2 lib)
target_link_libraries (Project2 ${EXTRA_LIBS})

# add test project
add_executable (UnitTests ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${TEST_SRCS})
target_link_libraries (UnitTests lib)
target_link_libraries (UnitTests gtest_main)

#
#
#   INSTALL
#
#

# add the install targets
#install (TARGETS Project2 DESTINATION bin)

#
#
#   TESTS
#
#

add_test (NAME unit COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/UnitTests)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add_subdirectory`, passing a single relative path to a subdirectory containing another `CMakeLists.txt`.

There is already one call to it, for googletest, in your own `CMakeLists.txt`, btw.

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html

Comment: This works for the library but when i try it with the executables cmake does not generate anything.